# How to wire two loads when one depends on the other?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 2 loads connected in parallel, and one power source. Obviously, they both get current independent of one another. Each load have an on/off key connected with, in series.

My goal is to let load (say: A) get current, if and only if load B gets current. However, load B should get current regardless of what's happening at A.

Edit: Device B is a TV LED screen. Device A is a separate speaker that I may or may not use with the TV (which has its own built-in speaker). The TV is already connected to a multiplug (with 1 switch for all) along with a DVD player. I connect the speaker to a separate dedicated wall outlet, that has a (modifiable) switch to turn on current. The 2 wall outlets are connected in parallel. Sometimes when I disconnect the TV the speaker stays unintentionally on. Which brings us to my question, if I can modify the 2 outlets:

Layman asking: Is there a way of doing so, using only wires and "know-how" (no fancy electric equipment at my disposal), and how?

If not, what's the alternative?

- Please support your answer with illustrations.

Comment: The actual project is a lcd screen, and a separate speaker. I connect each of them to a different wall outlet. One outlet supplies the other with electricity. The reason I didn't explain the real world application, is because I didn't wish to distract from the actual question. For instance, if one answer came why don't you use a multiplug, it won't be the answer I'm looking for. I have always resorted to work-arounds when I faced this particular issue. Now, here, I hope I can get the right answer. Please let me know which forum/community here is best suited to take my question?

Comment: There is far more distraction wondering what the underlying issue is than in seeing the underlying issue. Also, if there are solutions you've tried (for example a power strip), indicating that you've tried this and why it won't work for _your_ situation will save _everyone_ a lot of time in suggesting answers that you've already disposed of for some reason or another. [Edit] your post to include _as much_ detail as possible (without long narrative stories), then take the [tour] to learn about how this site operates differently than most while you wait for suggestions to pour in!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like fishing for a homework answer

Comment: You want to turn power on and off to your TV using a switched outlet? Most modern TVs expect to have power on all the time to maintain all their settings, like known inputs, last volume, known channels, color adjustments, etc. If you turn the power of to the socket, you'll have to reset all these things every time you turn on the switch. If you don't care about these things, then go ahead, but you may find it rather inconvenient and annoying.

Comment: @FreeMan, that's no longer true with most modern smart TVs.  Even my cheapo TCL ones will remember their settings after a power loss.  It does take a bit longer to boot up the first time after power is restored though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
 Line Hot-----SwitchB----------SwitchA----
                        |                |
                      LoadB            LoadA
                        |                |
 Line Neutral-----------------------------
```

This does require switches (typically a normal wall switch) you can wire to - hacking into device B after a built-in switch is going to void all sorts of things, not the least of which is your insurance if it causes a fire after your modification.

Comment: So, there's no way of doing this without separating switch B from load B. In other words, system A would depend on the current in system B (load & switch)?

Comment: @user1232949 Let me guess. Switch B is a *switch loop* and that's where you want to launch off from to extend the circuit?  You'll have to launch off the box that has both switch B switched-hot, and actual neutral (i.e. not a white wire in a switch loop).

Comment: You ruled out fancy electronics, so no. With fancy electronics you could do fancier things like sensing the current going to B and using that to control A, but you ruled them out, so you can't have what you cut yourself off from.

Comment: Well, what you put out seems reasonable, as a simple solution. What else is otherwise, possible: "what's the alternative"?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about "how", let's re-color ecnerwal's **schematic**, assigning colors to the wires **by function**.  You can buy colored tape and follow along at home if you like; in fact it will greatly improve both your understanding and your ease of working in those boxes.

Black = always-hot.  Red = swtiched-hot 1.  Blue = switched-hot 2.

[image]

*Note that this is a schematic NOT a wiring diagram.  Code requires the wiring be routed so each cable has equal and opposite current in its several wires.  This means cable layout is a tree topology - there are never loops*.

Look carefully at your wiring in both switch and lamp boxes, research or measure to determine what the wires actually do (ignoring their current default colors). And then wrap them with tape for 1 tape width like so.

Up in the lamp box, you definitely have switched-hot (red) and neutral (white).  You might have neutral at the switch, but as you can see, the switch doesn't need neutral at all - so you might not.

But once you've mapped the circuit, you know where you DO have switched-hot (red) and neutral.  **You must launch the additional circuit from there**.